# Привязать vue-multiselect к form

Tags: vue.js

Как из vue-multiselect передать значение value в форму

```js
<template>
    <div>
        <multiselect v-model="value"
                     placeholder="Выберите группу" label="name" track-by="name"
                     :options="options" :multiple="true"
                     :taggable="true"
                     @tag="addTag"></multiselect>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import Multiselect from 'vue-multiselect';
    import axios from 'axios';
    // register globally

    export default {
        components: {
            Multiselect
        },
        model: {
            prop: 'modelValue',
            event: 'change'
        },
        props: {
            apiUrl: {
                type: String,
            },
            data: {
                type: Array,
            },
            emptyValue: {
                type: String,
                default:null
            },
            customField: {
                default: null
            },
            modelValue: {
                default: null
            },
            selectClass: {
                default: null
            },
            withNoValue: {
                default: true
            },
            required: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: false
            },
            disabledOptions: {
                default: () => []
            },
            useSlot: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: false
            }
        },
        data: function () {
            return {
                isWaiting: false,
                selectData: null,
                value: [

                    ],
                options: []
            }
        },
        created: function() {
            this.loadData();
        },
        watch: {
            apiUrl: function() {
                this.loadData();
            },
            data:function() {
                this.loadData();
            },
        },
        methods: {
            addTag (newTag) {
                const tag = {
                    name: newTag,
                    code: newTag.substring(0, 2) + Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000000))
                }
            },
            loadData: function() {
                var self = this;

                this.isWaiting = true;
                if (this.apiUrl) {
                    axios.get(this.apiUrl, {
                        params: {
                            page: 1,
                            per_page: 100
                        }
                    }).then((response) => {
                        self.options = response.data.data
                        self.isWaiting = false;
                        self.$emit('loaded', self.options.length > 0 ? self.options[0].id : null);
                    });
                }else{
                    self.options = self.data;
                    self.isWaiting = false;
                    self.$emit('loaded', self.options.length > 0 ? self.options[0].id : null);
                }
            },
            onChange(e) {
                this.$emit('change', e.target.value);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: попробуйте удалить эту строку `prop: 'modelValue',`.

Comment: к сожалению не помогло